# Casting void * to a struct which is a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, casting

I have a linked list, where each node is of the following form:

```
struct queueItem
{
    struct carcolor *color;
    int id;
};
typedef struct queueItem *CustDetails;
```

I want to run the following function:

```
extern void mix(struct carcolor *v);
```

However, the function is run inside this:

```
void foo(void *v)    //v should be the pointer to the dequeued queueItem
{
    //do other stuff
    mix(v->color);
}
```

This gives the error:

```
request for member ‘color’ in something not a structure or union
```

How can I access `struct carcolor *color` when the function prototype is `void foo(void *v)`?

I tried casting `(struct queueItem) v` but that didn't work.

Comment: Cast to `((struct queueItem*)v)->color`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to cast to a pointer to the structure.

```
    mix(((struct queueItem *)v)->color);
```

---

What I like to do in these situations is to get a local pointer and use that

```
void foo(void *v)    //v should be the pointer to the dequeued queueItem
{
    struct queueItem *localpointer = v;
    //do other stuff
    mix(localpointer->color);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `struct queueItem` where you wrote `struct carcolor`? `v` is a pointer to `queueItem`, which holds a pointer to `struct carcolor`.

Comment: Hmm ... yes, I mean the same type as `v` was originally. Answer edited.

Comment: I think you forgot to edit the first line too. I'll mark your answer as correct once that's fixed.